# Sql get counts of consecutive dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.

| date | availability |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | y |
| 2021-01-16 | y |
| 2021-01-17 | y |
| 2021-01-18 | n |
| 2021-01-19 | n |
| 2021-01-20 | y |
| 2021-01-20 | n |

I wanted to have result with consecutive dates (more than one) with counts grouped by the availability. How can I achieve this result with mySQL query?

| date | counts | availability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 - 2021-01-17 | 3 | y |
| 2021-01-18 - 2021-01-19 | 2 | n |

Comment: select `date`, count(*) as counts , availability from table group by availability

Comment: Hi, please provide minimal example like suggested here https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Why last 2 rows are not mentioned in desired output? Why last row is not included into last output row? What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: I wanted to get results of consecutive dates with more than one with same availability. My mysql version 8.0.21

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a sequence and aggregate to get the individual sequences:

```
select availability, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (date - interval seqnum day), availabiility;
```

Then, I don't know if you just want `having count(*) > 1` or one more level of aggregation:

```
select min_date, availability, sum(cnt)
from (select availability, count(*) as cnt, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date)
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      group by (date - interval seqnum day), availabiility
    ) t
group by availibilty
```

Comment: Yes I need one more level of aggregation.